# Logistic regression using splines in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, splines

I am trying to reproduce the results from chapter 5.2.2 of [ESL](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) which is about logistic regression using splines. The dataset is the african heart disease dataset (downloadable from the website following data -> South African Heart Disease data)

I take a shortcut compared to the book since I directly select the relevant data. I do not perform data selection based on AIC criterion.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import patsy as patsy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

SAHeart = pd.read_csv(r"SAheart.data")
SAHeart.drop('row.names',axis = 1, inplace = True)
SAHeart = pd.get_dummies(SAHeart, columns = ['famhist'],drop_first=True) #convert categorial into binary
SAHeart = SAHeart.rename(columns={"famhist_Present": "famhist"})

SAHeart = SAHeart[['sbp','tobacco','ldl','famhist','obesity','age','chd']]

train, test = train_test_split(SAHeart, test_size=0.2)
trainResponse= train.chd

train.drop('chd',axis = 1, inplace = True)
test.drop('chd',axis = 1, inplace = True)

#train.drop('famhist',axis = 1, inplace = True)
#test.drop('famhist',axis = 1, inplace = True)

degFree = 4

data = pd.DataFrame()
for column in train:
    if column == 'famhist':
        y = patsy.dmatrix("bs(train[column], df=1, degree = 1)",
        {"train[column]": train[column]}, return_type='dataframe')
        y.columns = [train[column].name]*y.shape[1]
    if column != 'famhist':
        #start = SAHeart[column].min()
        #end = SAHeart[column].max()
        x = train[column]
        #! knots below = inner knots (=Total - boundary)
        #! for a natural cubic spline, df = number of TOTAL knots (inner + boundary)
        y = patsy.dmatrix("cr(train[column], df=4)",
        {"train[column]": train[column]}, return_type='dataframe')#patsy.cr(x, df=degFree)
        y.columns = [train[column].name]*y.shape[1]
    data = pd.concat([data,y.iloc[:,1:]],axis=1) #
    coeff = 0.1*np.ones((1,4))
        #plt.figure()
        #plt.plot(x,coeff*y

dataTest = pd.DataFrame()
for column in test:
    if column == 'famhist':
        y = patsy.dmatrix("bs(test[column], df=1, degree = 1)",
        {"train[column]": test[column]}, return_type='dataframe')
        y.columns = [test[column].name]*y.shape[1]

    if column != 'famhist':
        #start = SAHeart[column].min()
        #end = SAHeart[column].max()
        x = test[column]

        #! knots below = inner knots (=Total - boundary)
        #! for a natural cubic spline, df = number of TOTAL knots (inner + boundary)
        y = patsy.dmatrix("cr(test[column], df=4)",
                          {"test[column]": test[column]}, return_type='dataframe') #patsy.cr(x, df=degFree)
        y.columns = [test[column].name]*y.shape[1]
    dataTest = pd.concat([dataTest,y.iloc[:,1:]],axis=1)#natural cubic spline df = #knots, don't take intercept

#Add intercept term
data = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.ones((data.shape[0])),index=data.index),data],axis=1)
dataTest = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.ones((dataTest.shape[0])),index=dataTest.index),dataTest],axis=1)

logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1.0)
logistic.fit(data, trainResponse)
prediction = logistic.predict(dataTest)

coeffs = logistic.coef_

#plot sbp related data
span = np.linspace(min(train['sbp']),max(train['sbp']),100).reshape(-1,1)
spanSpline = patsy.dmatrix("cr(span, df=4)",
                          {"span": span}, return_type='dataframe') #patsy.cr(span, df=degFree)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(span, np.dot(spanSpline, coeffs[0][0:degFree+1].T),marker=".")
```

But I don"t get the same figure for f_hat(sbp) as you can see from the picture below (up = my f_hat, below = ESL book f_hat). The picture is obtained by the last lines in the code (i.e. below the "plot sbp related data comment")

[image: MyAnswer]
[image: ESL_answer]

Comment: I doubt if you will have any help here with python. Most questions are related to R rather than python

Comment: I think the language does not matter much. I am sure the issue lies somewhere else (spline definition, degrees of freedom, intercept term,...)

Comment: The most common problem with "sklearn logistic regression vs something" is in regularization. Are you sure that in ESL they also use quadratic penalty with C=1?

Comment: From ESL: "This actually implies three rather than two interior knots (chosen at uniform quantiles of sbp), plus two boundary knots at the extremes of the data, since we exclude the constant term from each of the $h_j$." That's 5 total; you only seem to have used 4.

Comment: R code to reproduce this plot can be found [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~richard/download/courses/stat_learn_2007/glm_and_splines.r).

Comment: Useful. Patsy & R ns() function do not provide the same data. I will have to understand why

Comment: I couldn't answer above. But I am having the same issues and I would like to understand why the Patsy in Python and R ns () functions do not provide the same results. Somehow @FenryrMKIII did you found out why?

Comment: you might want to look at Introduction to statistical learning textbook (which has both R and python versions).https://www.statlearning.com/

Comment: see https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spline-regression.html#natural-and-cyclic-cubic-regression-splines ... it says it should be compatible with the *bases* of `mgcv`